# Shiny App works locally, but not on the ShinyApps.io server

Tags: r, shiny

I deploy my app and opens up, but returns an error message and says to check my logs.

I believe it is something with my postgres db connection, or the logic I use to graph that information.

```
server <- function(input, output){


# Get Athlete Data From Database
DataTable <- reactive({
  query <- DBI::sqlInterpolate(con, queryTable, athleteName = 
  input$athleteSearch)
  DataTable <- RPostgreSQL::dbGetQuery(con, query)
  return(DataTable)
})


output$lineGraph <- renderPlot({
  require(input$athleteSearch)

# Create Line Graph
  LineGraph <-
  DataTable() %>%
  mutate(date_tested = as.Date(date_tested)) %>%
  select(date_tested, strength, fluidity, power, momentum) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date_tested, y= strength)) + geom_line(aes(group = 1, 
  color = "strength"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(x = date_tested, y = fluidity, group = 1, color = 
  "fluidity"),  size = 1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(x = date_tested, y = power, group = 1, color = 'power'),  
  size = 1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(x = date_tested, y = momentum, group = 1, color = 
  'momentum'), size = 1.5) +
  xlab("Date Tested") + ylab("Score") + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c('red', 'orange', 'dark red', 'black')) + 
  theme_bw()

  return(LineGraph)
})

}
```

This is the section that does not work

It says "an error has occurred.  Check your logs."

logs return this message:

> Warning in if (!loaded) { : 2019-08-22T13:41:22.289154+00:00
>   shinyapps[1104020]:   the condition has length > 1 and only the first
>   element will be used 2019-08-22T13:41:22.289735+00:00
>   shinyapps[1104020]: c("Loading required package: $", "Loading required
>   package: input", "Loading required package: report")
>   2019-08-22T13:41:22.290211+00:00 shinyapps[1104020]: Failed with
>   error:  ‘'package' must be of length 1’
>   2019-08-22T13:41:22.292493+00:00 shinyapps[1104020]:   the condition
>   has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
>   2019-08-22T13:41:22.292492+00:00 shinyapps[1104020]: Warning in if
>   (!loaded) { : 2019-08-22T13:41:22.292920+00:00 shinyapps[1104020]:
>   c("Loading required package: $", "Loading required package: input",
>   "Loading required package: report") 2019-08-22T13:41:22.293325+00:00
>   shinyapps[1104020]: Failed with error:  ‘'package' must be of length
>   1’

Comment: Are you sure you want `require` and not `req` ?

Comment: What do you try to do with `require(input$athleteSearch)`? `require` is used to load packages

Comment: I switched require to req, thank you very much.  That did fix one of the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have your `library()` calls in your code as they are missing above.

Anyway, I believe you are missing the info about the host/port/user/password for the database you want to connect to. See https://github.com/r-dbi/RPostgres.

Comment: I did load the libraries on a separate script, I just did not post it here.  I have a connection here:  

pg <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(pg, user = "postgres", password = "*******", host = "localhost", port = 5433, dbname = 'postgres')

will that work on the server?  Because it works locally.

Comment: I think not. When you have host = 'localhost' on shinyapps you are suggesting that the database is there. So you need the actual host of the database, see the example in the documentation: `host = 'HOST', # i.e. 'ec2-54-83-201-96.compute-1.amazonaws.com'`

Comment: I hosted the database on aws rds so it is remote.  I also changed my code to now look like this:

pg <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(pg,
                 user = "postgres",
                 password = "******",
                 host = 'engineered-performance.cvpteihkoksl.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com', 
                 port = 5432,
                 dbname = "name"
)

It works locally again but still will not work on the shinyapps.io server.  I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: So what is the error you are having now? When you say 'it works locally' do you mean that the app ran from rstuido connects to the database on aws?

Comment: For some reason the app is not reading my query objects now.   I have:
queryTable <- 'SELECT * FROM JumpData'

and now the error in the log reads 
Warning: Error in DBI::dbGetQuery: object 'queryTable' not found

When I say locally, I mean just pushing "run app" and running it on my computer and not the shinyapps.io server.

Comment: I got it working now.  For some reason I couldn't save the query string as an object, it worked by putting the actual query string in dbGetQuery.  Thank you for your help.